# Support of hierarchy level in fast excel

Tags: java, fast-excel

Could you please  help me understand is there any way to generate excel sheet where in we can see format like   hierarchy  level is clasped with + button e.g.
+Info
On click on expand
Info
Info1
info2

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.